# Weierstrass Substitution using $t = \tan x$ and $t = \tan\frac{x}{2}$

Tags: integration

I am solving Integrals of rational functions in terms of trigonometric functions. I found out that I can use the substitution using $t = \tan x$ and $t = \tan\frac{x}{2}$. Are both methods considered as Weierstrass Substitution?

Based on references (i.e. https://www.math24.net/weierstrass-substitution) Weierstrass Substitution is considered to be the substitution using $t = \tan\frac{x}{2}$ only and the use of $t = \tan x$ is just an extension of Weierstrass Substitution. Is this correct?

Comment: I've only heard of the "tangent half-angle" substitution being referred to as "Weierstrass".  It is not widely called by that name and I have been trying to find out why the association is even made.  (Euler already knew it...natch...)  Notes I've seen posted by a few people suggest that James Stewart called it by that name in his textbooks and that has since "stuck" with quite a few people.  I haven't seen anyone point to an earlier usage.

Comment: @boojum: Euler is everywhere, so why not call it by the second discoverer Weierstrass ;) Btw, we have Euler substitution already in integral calculus.

Comment: It isn't clear that Weierstrass had anything to do with it.  I've been checking on what historians have to say about it.  I just came from the HSM Stack Exchange where one person says they've yet to find anything in Weierstrass' work to justify naming it for him.  (My own _guess_ is that since it is related to the "rational parameterization" of the circle, it may have been something he taught and that Stewart in some way picked up on that.)

Comment: @boojum: Wow, I should be having a read on it. Thanks :D